# Can we set Quotas in Azure Open AI

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Can we set quotas at Resource group level in Azure Open AI so that we can prevent the usage by all customers, Is it possible to have separate quotas for Prompts, completions, and training.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quota increases apply to rate limits (Requests per minute and Tokens per Minute) and are applied at the resource and model level. Quota increases do not adjust resources limits.

[Quotas](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ai-cognitive-services-blog/generative-ai-for-developers-exploring-new-tools-and-apis-in/ba-p/3817003) can be set at the resource group level, with separate quotas for prompts, completions, and training. Customers can view their current usage and remaining quota in the Azure portal.